Calculating the interval of convergence of $G(s)$
Define the function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as
$$
\begin{equation}
  g(n) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1, & n=1\\
    2, & n \text{ is composite or } n = 2\\
    n, & n \text{ is prime and } n \geq 3
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
What numbers $s \in \mathbb{C}$ make the following series $$G(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n^s}$$ converge? Can I use the radius of convergence to find these numbers? I believe it is $\mathfrak{Re}(s)>1$ because the series look very similar to the prime-zeta function and the famous zeta function. Is this true?

Hints:

What about $\sum_{p}g(p)/p^s$ (the sum is over primes)?
What about the difference of this series with $G(s)$?


The answer to 1. (hence the final answer) is $\Re s\geqslant 2, s\neq 2$.

Is the question number 2 a comparison question or as the algebraic subtraction context?

@YoyosTutoring: The latter. The result of the subtraction certainly converges if $\Re s>1$. Which is enough to conclude that the answer to "1." is the final one.
